# Getting 2 class objects with 1 query in parse.com using Pointers

Tags: class, parse-platform

I have 2 classes and I need 1 column each from both the classes, I can do that using 2 different queries but that calls for 2 API calls, I know that currently it isnt possible to call 2 classes with 1 query however I was wondering how do pointers work, and if it was possible to use pointers to get data from a separate class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a one-to-one relationship between the two classes then it is pretty easy.

Lets assume you have `Class1` and `Class2`. Just add a property to one of them, I'll use `Class1.relatedClass2`.

Now when you query for `Class1` you can tell it to include your `relatedClass2`, which will include the object that property points to.

If instead you have a one-to-many relationship, and there aren't too many, you can use an array of pointers, e.g. `Class1.relatedClass2s`. The same include statement would mean that the array is now populated with each related `Class2` object.

Comment: I am stuck on this one again, it worked for android (java) but now I need help in javascript (cloud code). It is a one-to-one relationship and my code includes the column in class1 which has a pointer to class2. Now how do I get the object of class2? something like var myObject = results[0].getObject("relationshipBetweenClasses");
This doesnt work

Comment: If you have included the relation in your query, then you can simply use `results[0].get("propertyName");` to get the fully populated class.